# how to stop already signedIn user to sign in from other browser

Tags: java, gwt

I have a login funcitonality in my application , 
where i am able to store the user in a session 
and i am also able to stop user to signIn , if he is already Signed in on the same browser .. 
But if a signedIn user tries to logIn again from a DIFFERENT browser i am not able to stop him .

here is the code..

I am using this

```
             session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);
             User loggedInUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
```

Now this loggedInUser have the user object if a loggedInUser tries to get in the application from the SAME browser in another tab (SO it works for me)

BUT this loggedInUser is null if a loggedInUser tries to get in the application from the DIFFERENT browser(SO its not working for me)

here is the code..

```
            public User signIn(String userid, String password)  {
    String result = "";
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "applicationContext.xml");
    MySQLRdbHelper rdbHelper = (MySQLRdbHelper) ctx.getBean("ManagerTie");
    User user = (User) rdbHelper.getAuthentication(userid, password);
    if(user!=null)
    {
        session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);
        User loggedInUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

        if(loggedInUser != null && user.getId() == loggedInUser.getId()){
            user.setId(0);
        }else{
        session=getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        }


    }
    return user;
```

I am using JAVA , GWT

Answer (score 2):

Yes by storing  `static` map on server side,Which stores `User Id` as a key and `Session`  as `value`.

Here is working code from my bag directly.

```
class SessionObject implements HttpSessionBindingListener {
        User loggedInUser;
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SessionObject.class);
        public SessionObject(User loggedInUser) {
            this.loggedInUser=loggedInUser;
        }
        public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
            LoggedInUserSessionUtil.getLogggedUserMap()
                                      .put(loggedInUser, event.getSession());
            return;
        }

        public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) { 
            try {
                LoggedInUserSessionUtil.removeLoggedUser(loggedInUser);
                return;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             }

    }
```

[Java tip I followed](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/12/httpsessionbindinglistener-example) and [Java2s link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/SessionEventsimplementsHttpSessionBindingListener.htm)  while I developed.

Comment: Thats a class which contained the map  and its getters and setters.