# Restrict a user login to single session at a time using java, hibernate web application without spring

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am developing a web application using Java , Hibernate and JSF.
I want a user to restrict to login to a single session only, that I if user is already logged in I don't want to login it back from other location without logging out the first session.

Can anyone help in letting know how that can be achieved. To mention that as per my requirements I can't use spring or its any feature.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to maintain a application scoped `Set<Long>` that contains all the logged in user logical identifier (if you expect too many user may be write it to DB)

Upon login attempt check if the user is already logged in by checking his/her identifier in that `Set`

Upon logout remove user from that `Set`

Upon session expiration remove user from that `Set`

Use [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to remove user identifier from Set [`sessionDestroyed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29)

If you persist that data out of memory, upon app shutdown clear that external data source

Comment: +1 to that, but does this take in account cluster environment?  Maybe that doesn't matter for OP anyway

Comment: Can you let me how to remove it upon session expiration, as after session expires how should I know which user info to be removed from the application scoped set

Comment: +1, This way we implemented. One session must be invalid to open another for that user .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548636/how-to-stop-already-signedin-user-to-sign-in-from-other-browser/18548717#18548717 ,with slight modification , A map with user object and Session Object

Comment: @Jorge if you mean there are multiple nodes of application server, then may be serialize that Set to centralized data server (redis/mysql/)

Comment: "A map with user object and Session Object" you are sticking the Session object in a Map you manage yourself? That sets off an alarm in my head, you should not be creating hard references to a server managed resources because then you might interfere with its internal mechanisms. I would store a WeakReference to the session object in stead.